# How can I replace a cursor in sql server for printing an output

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I want to know how to replace a cursor in SQL Server because it performs badly. I tried using a CTE for list recursively but I don't know how to output the columns. I want to print it because I want paste the output in a .txt file.

This is the CTE so far:

```
WITH EmpleadosRec (EmpNombre,EmpID) 
AS
(
    SELECT[First Name],ID from employees where id=1
    UNION ALL
    select e.[First Name], ID+1 from employees as e
    INNER JOIN EmpleadosRec er
    ON e.id = er.EmpID 
    WHERE e.id < 5
)
select *
from EmpleadosRec
```

Comment: Re indent - above the editor there's a button with {} - you can select your code and format using this button

Comment: Where do you execute this code? In SSMS?

Comment: yes i executed it and its bring me the results correctly but i want to know how to print them, and how can i put the code of the cursor ?

Comment: In SSMS right-click the results window and chose "Save As..."

Comment: if you were successful before using a cursor, would you mind posting that as well? So it would be easier to see what the expected output is.

Comment: Alternatively: `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F` swaps the results output to file (Results to grid: CTRL+D, Results to Text: CTRL+T)... The execute your query.

Comment: Because i want to output that with a print or something like that.Is it possible?

Comment: Its not exactly what im looking for but its useful, thanks @gvee. How can I notify that my question was answered?

Comment: @NaviGhost are you saying that my suggestion(s) solved the issue for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id int = 1
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(50)

WHILE @id < 5
BEGIN
    SELECT @FirstName = [First Name] from employees where id = @id 

    Print '@FirstName = ' + @FirstName + ' @id = ' + CAST(@id as varchar(50))
    SET @id = @id + 1
END
GO
```

But this method is bad if you process a large number of rows.

In this case check [MSDN bcp Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

```
bcp "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person ORDER BY LastName, Firstname" queryout Contacts.txt -c -T
```

Also in SQL Management Studio
Menu Query -> Results To -> Results To File

Comment: thanks! this solved my issue.I ll investigate more about MSDN bcp Utility